# Laravel 4 - Showing edit form with OLD data input as well as DB information

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im making a edit form for my app and i was wondering if someone could tell me how to get the data from the database into my text field.

I can locate the record i need to edit based on the users click, and i can display the information if i do the following:

```
value="{{ $letter->subject }}"
```

BUT, the problem im having is that when i run it through the validation and there is an error, it comes back with the database information instead of the OLD data.

So my questions is. Is there a way to serve up the database information first and then when it goes through the validatior, validate the information the user has edited?

Currently to validate the text field and bring the data back incase of error, im using

```
Input::old('subject')
```

Is there a parameter for that old bit that allows me to put in the DB data?

Cheers,

Comment: BigJobbies - can I please suggest you visit Laracasts.com - it is a paid service, but has great tutorials on getting started with Laravel with will cover many of your basic questions. Its by far the best Laravel training resource available.

Comment: p.s. the answer is you need to use ->withInput() on your return when the validation fails - to allow the form to be populated with the old input instead of the DB.

Comment: Actually it has alot of free guides as well - https://laracasts.com/tags/free

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is form model binding http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding:

```
{{ Form::model($letter, ['route' => ['letters.update', $letter->id], 'method' => 'put']) }}
   // your fields like:
   {{ Form::text('someName', null, ['class' => 'someHTMLclass' ...]) }}
   // no default values like Input::old or $letter->something!
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This way you form will be populated by the $letter data (passed from the controller for example).

Now, if you have on your countroller:

```
// in case of invalid data
return Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

then on the redirect your form will be repopulated with input values first, not the original model data.

Comment: awesome solution ;)

Answer (score 10):

Hey you could validate and return ->withInput() and then in your actual form, check if there is Input::old() and display it, otherwise display from the db.

example:

```
<input type="text" name="subject" 
value="{{ (Input::old('subject')) ? Input::old('subject') : $letter->subject }}">
```

Or you could go the other way and define the variable and do a regular if statement, instead of the ternary one! Up to you to decide what you want to use!

Comment: Like a charm for non Laravel forms

Comment: Any experts who can show me the value for this kind of input: `<input type="number" min="0" name="services[{{$service->id}}][price_15]"class="form-control">`? It's a loop per service from DB.

Answer (score 3):

Make it more simple and clean

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="{{ (Input::old('subject')) ?: $letter->subject }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for Laravel 4 but in Laravel 5, function **old** takes second param, default value if no old data in session.

Please check this answer [Best practice to show old value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42002942/1158777)