# How to return inputs in Laravel 8 (rows) after failed validation

Tags: laravel, validation, session, flash-message

Im using Laravel8, and I want to return the inputs after failed validation in the form.

**VIEW:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>{{__("Coupon Code")}} <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input type="text" maxlength="50" required value="{{$row->code}}" placeholder="{{__("Unique Code")}}" name="code" class="form-control">
```

Controller:

```
public function store( Request $request,$id ){
    $request->validate([
        'code'=>[
            'required',
            'max:50',
            'string',
            'alpha_dash',
            Rule::unique('bravo_coupons')->ignore($id > 0 ? $id : false)
        ],
        'amount'=>['required'],
    ]);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean the input values ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best practice to show old value when editing a form in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461677/what-is-the-best-practice-to-show-old-value-when-editing-a-form-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `old()` [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old) like so:

```
<input value="{{ old('code') }}">
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working in rows, in normal data its working as {{ old('cancellation', $translation->cancellation) }}..